# How to compile openssl for only two functions

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I am trying to use openssl to encode a simple string, no need of decrypting it.
I am using the functions

```
AES_set_encrypt_key()
AES_cfb128_encrypt()
```

I need I think only the include:

```
 #include <openssl/aes.h>
```

I couldn't find instructions in the web or in the openssl website about how to compile the source code for a visual studio project.  Does anyone know how this should be done?
Can I compile only the code relevant for these two functions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you want to use these functions in your code. You don't need to compile OpenSSL for that.

Install the package on your development machine (if developing for Windows, you can get the latest installer [here](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)). It will contain header files you need to include in your code (they will be in `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl`), static libraries you need to link your application against (in `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC`) and DLL your application needs to run (in `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin`).

So, in your code you'll have:

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
...
AES_set_encrypt_key(...);
...
AES_cfb128_encrypt(...);
...
```

Your compiler needs to know the path to header you included (path to `openssl` directory) so you need to provide it. If you are using Visual Studio, open project settings and add `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\include` to Additional Include Directories.

In the Linker section, add `ssleay32MDd.lib;libeay32MDd.lib;` to Additional Dependencies so your linker know which OpenSSL libraries to look for. Path to these libraries - `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC` - add to Additional Library Directories.

Be careful with these libraries: they need to be linked against the same runtime library as your application. Their suffix tells you which runtime library they are linked against: libraries I mention above have suffix MDd which means they use Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) - so you will include them if your application use the same runtime (check this in Code Generation->Runtime Library setting).

Your application will build now but to run it, your binary will need to have access to OpenSSL DLL `libeay32.dll` as depends on it. Copy that DLL to system directory or to the directory you're running your app or add path `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin` to `Path` environment variable.